# Going from array of objects to object of objects in Typescript

Tags: typescript

What is a good use of types for the case where you have an array of objects, and you want to transform the data to an object of objects keyed on a given key of the objects in the array?

For example:

```
[
    {
        name: "alice", 
        id: "54dc2a",
        age: 23
    },
    {
        name: "bob",
        id: "662adf",
        age: 60
    }
]
```

You could convert by one of the fields like `convert(myArr, "name")`. Where the result could be:

```
{
    "alice": {
        name: "alice", 
        id: "54dc2a",
        age: 23
    },
    "bob": {
        name: "bob",
        id: "662adf",
        age: 60
    }
}
```

My first attempt, which gives an error:

```ts
type Collection<T> = { [k: string]: T }

const convert = <T,>(arr: T[], key: string & keyof T) => {
    const obj: Collection<T> = {}
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      obj[item[key]] = item
    })
    return obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the logic here, it works with a more specific type definition. The issue is that the typecheck fails because the value in item[key] needs to be a string in order to be a key in the collection, but since T is generic this is not ensured.

I can't see a way to keep it as generic as it is now while still ensuring a value behind an arbitrary key is a string. Unless you come up with a smart type definition, you may have to define the key, or use `//@ts-ignore` to escape the typecheck.